# PHP cUrl Rate Limiting per API

Tags: php, api, curl, limit, throttling

I am working on an API mashup in PHP of various popular APIs and would liek to implement rate limiting to ensure i am playing nice.

I did some research and have taken a look at CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT but I have some confusion about how they function.

As I understand it, likely incorrectly:

```
CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS
---
  Each script that calls a cUrl request opens a connection.  
  When the MAXCONNECTS limit is reached, then the server delays the request.

CURLOPT_TIMEOUT
---
  The amount of time that the server will wait to make a connection.  
  Working with MAXCONNECTS, does that mean that cUrl will make the listed 
  number of connections and then wait up to TIMEOUT for an open thread?
```

So-- I am, obviously, very confused about how cUrl actually functions with these parameters.  The application I am developing needs to limit cUrl requests at different limits for each API I am calling.  As I understand things, the cUrl options are server wide?  Is there some method of attaching a token to a specific cUrl call and applying the limit per API that way?  Do I need to work some global/shared memory magic?

Your truly and considerably confused,
Samantha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS is just the maximum number of simultaneous requests.
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT is the time cURL will wait before abording request in the case that there is no answer.

You'll have to work you limits manually

Comment: So, how does MAXCONNECTS work?  You can reset it with each cURL request.  How does it count out?  Also, you say work your limits manually: what way would you recommend going about this?

Comment: I don't realy know CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS would work if you set different value on different request, but in you case it's not what you are looking for.
I'd recommend storing each request in a database, a file, or APC var, and simply abord or delay any request that would go over you limit.